# Jinja2 include with batch filter

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to include a template inside a for loop with a batch filter applied
But I can't figure out how/if I can include for each object in the list that the filter returns

I see people online selecting from the loop like so:

```
{% for result in results %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ result[0] }}</td>
            <td>{{ result[1] }}</td>
            <td>{{ result[2] }}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I just can't figure out how to include for each in the list
My code is as follows:

```
{% for post in posts | batch(2, '&nbsp;') %}
        <tr>
            <td style="Width: 10%; height: auto">
                {% include '_post.html' %}
            </td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Including](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#include) portions of a template in a loop/filter construction is perfectly fine.

Using your example, to build a table of posts using a partial template for each batch, you'll need:

The template with the loop/filter where you include the partial:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for row in posts | batch(2) %}
        {% include "row.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The **partial template** "row.html":

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ row[0].title }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[0].author }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[1].title }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[1].author }}</td>
</tr>
```

Another option would be to iterate over the batch partition again and use a simpler partial template:

The template:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for row in posts | batch(2) %}
        <tr>
        {% for col in row  %}
            {% include "col.html" %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And "col.html":

```
<td>{{ col.title }}</td>
<td>{{ col.author }}</td>
```

If it's not working, double check the variable names, partial names, etc.